# change codeigniter .htaccess to web.config error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis, web-config

I trying to use codeigniter on IIS, I was able to config php to work on IIS but when I tried to change the .htaccess to web.config it gives me error

my htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^admin(.*) index.php/admin$1
RewriteRule ^supervisor/([0-9]+)(.*) index.php/supervisor_$1/$2
RewriteRule ^moder/(.*)/([0-9]+)(.*) index.php/moder/$1/$2
rewriteRule ^(login|logoff)(.*) index.php/base/$1$2
RewriteRule ^(attachment|meeting|thread|attachments|profile|search|roles|cat)(.*) index.php/moder/$1$2
RewriteRule ^(about|contact|new_majlis|sk|supervideo|superandsk|guest)(.*) index.php/page/$1$2
RewriteRule ^(2.2-release-notes)(.*) index.php/page/release_notes
RewriteRule ^page/(change_lang)/(.*) index.php/page/$1/$2
```

and for my web.config code :

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
<rule name="rule 1m">
    <match url="^admin(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/admin{R:1}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2m">
    <match url="^supervisor/([0-9]+)(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/supervisor_{R:1}/{R:2}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3m">
    <match url="^moder/(.*)/([0-9]+)(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/moder/{R:1}/{R:2}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4m">
    <match url="^(login|logoff)(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/base/{R:1}{R:2}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 5m">
    <match url="^(attachment|meeting|thread|attachments|profile|search|roles|cat)(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/moder/{R:1}{R:2}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 6m">
    <match url="^(about|contact|new_majlis|sk|supervideo|superandsk|guest)(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/page/{R:1}{R:2}"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 7m">
    <match url="^(2.2-release-notes)(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/page/release_notes"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 8m">
    <match url="^page/(change_lang)/(.*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/page/{R:1}/{R:2}"  />
</rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

i still get this screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has it's own routing class which will make you're life much more simple especially if there is possibility of switching between Server OS's.

The following web.config file is the bare basics of getting CI to work with IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|ttf|woff" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then in **application/config/routes.php** an example line would be

```
$route['page/(change_lang)/(.*)'] = 'page/$1/$2';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANKS FOR YOU REPLAY I STILL HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM

Comment: Detailed Error Information:
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code    0x8007000d
Config Error    
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\KKU\web.config
Requested URL    http://localhost:80/KKU
Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\KKU
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User    Not yet determined